# Extract substring using regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to extract only the part `0000520621` from the string `nmg-22373-0000520621-001-010000520621`.

I would like to use regular expressions in `python` for this task.

Can you help me in doing so?

Comment: why not check for the substring?  ( '0000520621' in my_str )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regexp to get the third member of a list. Just split your string by the minus character and pick it's third member.

```
test = 'nmg-22373-0000520621-001-010000520621'
test.split('-')[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = 'nmg-22373-0000520621-001-010000520621'
expected = re.search('22373-(.+?)-001',l)
if expected:
    print expected.group(1)
```